# SIGABRT QT debugger

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, qt-creator, gdbserver

Hi when I try to debug a simple QT Application:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  QTranslator translator;
  const QStringList uiLanguages = QLocale::system().uiLanguages();
  for (const QString &locale : uiLanguages) {
    const QString baseName = "helloworld_" + QLocale(locale).name();
    if (translator.load(":/i18n/" + baseName)) {
        a.installTranslator(&translator);
        break;
    }
  }
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
 }
```

I recieve a SIGABRT:

[image]

and the application output is:

```
No protocol specified
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0.0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized.
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

When I just run the application, it works without problems.

Additional information, in my setup I specified the DISPLAY environment:

[image]

What am I missing? Why my application when is debugged cannot connect to display :0.0 and sends a SIGABRT?

Comment: Sounds like yor kit isn't built or installed correctly or you have a mixup of your build of kit and system-built plugin. Worse case scenario is system is broken after bad package update. Make sure you run configure correctly. There might be problems if you rebuikt qt after adding/modifying its dependencies but didn't run cobfigure, only make.

Answer (score 0):

**Update;** OP's issue was about running debug-session as `root` (instead of normal user), but below steps may help someone.

**Old answer;**

Your logs say:

> "Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found."

**And if that log is NOT mistaken,** your "Debug" target's architecture isn't compatible with "xcb", **while** your "Release" target's is.

**But if that log is mistaken,** try to copy required plugins (like "xcb") to be beside your App's *debug* executable (which's inside your build directory).

> **Note** that some plugins require to be placed in a specific sub-folder, else Qt will ignore them.

Finally, also try setting the `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1`
(environment variable, not a `qmake` setting), before launching App and/or debug-session.

Comment: This answer was not the solution for me, but it helped me to find out the problem: I added QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 and I found that plugin was found "loaded library "/usr/lib/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so". The problem was that protocol was not specified, even if I exported DISPLAY, it turned out that running the debug session as a user on the target instead of being on root it worked.